# Bounds for Matrix Inner Product based on singular values

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, matrix-decomposition, singular-values, matrix-norms

Lewis(1995) " The convex analysis of unitarily invariant matrix functions " states the result by von neumann that $\langle X,Y \rangle \leq \langle \sigma_X,\sigma_Y \rangle$. Does anyone know any easy proof or reference for it. i couldnt understand the reference cited in the paper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called the [von-Neumann trace inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_inequality#Von_Neumann%27s_trace_inequality_and_related_results). For a reference: this is given in Horn and Johnson's *Matrix Analysis* as Theorem 7.4.1.1. For a more powerful result, you could use corollary IV.2.6 of Bhatia's *Matrix Analysis*.